# google chrome runs stackoverflow without graphic

Tags: 16.04, graphics, google-chrome

I am using google chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, when I open the stackoverflow website I got the website without the graphics , can someone help me to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Same problem with Firefox Ubuntu 16.04. Private mode also doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Does the same happen with other web browsers (e. g. Firefox or Epiphany)? How is the computer connected to the internet? Did you configure it to use a (web) proxy server of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

Your adblocker or a proxy / firewall seems to block the domain from which the CSS files are served.

Check your adblock/firewall/proxy logs and settings and allow connections to **cdn.sstatic.net**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening it in incognito mode? 
In that case your browser extensions will be disabled. If it working in that way I suppose the adblocker will be the problem. I was facing similar issue yesterday (with different sites).

Comment: yes it works in incognito mode, thank you for your answer